# How Can I Move This <td> Tag To The Next Line?

Tags: php, css

I have a problem:

Here's a block of the code:

```
function draw()
{
    $out_string="";
    $out_string.=$this->script;
    reset($this->fields);
    $num_list_box=0;
    while( $field = each($this->fields) )
    {
    if (isset($this->fields[$field[1]->field]->options))
           {
           if (preg_match("/<script type=\"text\/javascript\">/i",$this->fields[$field[1]->field]->options[0][1])&& $this->fields[$field[1]->field]->value!="")
               {
               if ($num_list_box==0) $out_string.= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">levels.forValue(\"".$field_prev[0]."\").setDefaultOptions(\"".$this->fields[$field[1]->field]->value."\");</script>\n";
                   else $out_string.= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">levels.forValue(\"".$field_prev[0]."\").forValue(\"".$field_prev[1]."\").setDefaultOptions(\"".$this->fields[$field[1]->field]->value."\");</script>\n";
               $field_prev[]=$this->fields[$field[1]->field]->value;
               $num_list_box++;
               } else
               {
               $field_prev[0]=$this->fields[$field[1]->field]->value;
               $num_list_box=0;
               }

           }

    }

    $out_string.=$this->draw_title();
    $out_string.=$this->draw_header();
    $out_string.= "<table class=\"forms\">\n";
    $field=array_keys($this->fields);
    reset($field);
    $ind_first=true;
    while( list($pos,$field_name) = each($field) )
    {
       if ($this->num_cols>0) {
       if ($this->fields[$field_name]->col==1){
          if ($ind_first) $ind_first=false;else $out_string.="</tr>";
          $out_string.="<tr><td class=\"field_title\">";}
          else $out_string.="<td class=\"field_title\">";
       $out_string.= $this->fields[$field_name]->title."</td>";
       $colspan="";
       if ($this->num_cols>1) {
           if ($this->fields[$field_name]->col==1 && array_key_exists($pos+1,$field) && $this->fields[$field[$pos+1]]->col==1)
             $colspan="colspan=\"3\"";
          }
       $out_string.="<td class=\"field_value\" $colspan>";
       $out_string.=$this->fields[$field_name]->draw()."</td>";
       } else
       {
       if ($ind_first) $ind_first=false;else $out_string.="</tr>";
       $out_string.="<tr><td class=\"field_value\">".$this->fields[$field_name]->title."<br />";
       $out_string.=$this->fields[$field_name]->draw()."</td>";
       }
    }
    $out_string.= "</tr></table>\n";
    return $out_string;
}
```

This above block of code produces something like this:

[image]

I want it such that in the example provided that the word "Transaction" is above the text box.

Please help, the person that programmed this part is indisposed and we've got a deadline.

Thanks for the help.

P.S. The CSS class name for the text is: `field_title` and the one for the textbox is `field_value`

Thanks once more.

Comment: The first thing I would suggest would to **not** use tables to display non-tabular data. Instead use `<div>`s `<span>`s and other elements with proper CSS styling.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to debug that code to find out when the label "Transaction" is getting inserted into that cludge of table code.  Once you find where "Transaction" is inserted you can then create new logic to add another TR that colspans the table and place the label on that new row.

Good luck, looks like a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is apparently building a rather complex form based on some data (`$fields` property of the class). I guess some "field settings" (like `col`) describe how the form should look like.

So, your code is doing things that are neither described in your question nor in the code itself. Furthermore, we have no clue what the complete form currently looks like, so we can't even guess the intention of the code.

Your request, to let the description appear above the selection box(?) could be done probably throwing away half of the code, but that won't help you.

PS: Please check the FAQ - this site is for questions, not for finding people to do your (or elses) work. You should really have a programmer solve your problem directly having access to the whole page.